# DataNucleus, Maven, schema-create fails

Tags: java, maven, datanucleus

I am trying to create a maven project with DataNucleus and MySQL. However, when i try to build and `mvn datanucleus:schema-create` the project, I get a failure. I can't figure out why.

Here is the `persistence.xml` class, and it *is* present in the `classes/META-INF` folder of the built project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- JDO tutorial "unit" -->
    <persistence-unit name="Tutorial">
        <class>hello.Counter</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/glu" />
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName"
                value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" value="root" />

            <property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll" value="true" />
            <property name="datanucleus.schema.validateTables" value="true" />
            <property name="datanucleus.schema.validateConstraints"
                value="true" />
            <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
                value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is the `pom.xml` i am trying to use.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.sf0.one</groupId>
    <artifactId>two</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>glu</name>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.2.0</version> -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <!-- scope>runtime</scope -->
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-accessplatform-jdo-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>3.2</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-release</version>


                <configuration>
                    <api>JDO</api>
                    <persistenceUnitName>Tutorial</persistenceUnitName>
                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/src/main/resources/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

The error that I get is:

```
~>2015-02-23 00:26:55 DEBUG MetaData:58 - Class "hello.Counter" field "count" : Adding Meta-Data for field since it didnt appear in the Meta-Data definition.
~>2015-02-23 00:26:55 DEBUG MetaData:58 - Initialising all MetaData ...
~>2015-02-23 00:26:55 DEBUG MetaData:58 - Class "hello.Counter" : Initialising Meta-Data
~>2015-02-23 00:26:55 DEBUG MetaData:58 - MetaData Management : Load of Metadata complete
~>2015-02-23 00:26:55 DEBUG Datastore:58 - Creating StoreManager for datastore
~>2015-02-23 00:26:55 ERROR Datastore:125 - Exception thrown creating StoreManager. See the nested exception
There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:223)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.datanucleus.store.schema.SchemaTool.getNucleusContextForMode(SchemaTool.java:693)
    at org.datanucleus.store.schema.SchemaTool.main(SchemaTool.java:286)
~>2015-02-23 00:26:55 ERROR SchemaTool:125 - Error creating NucleusContext
There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:223)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.datanucleus.store.schema.SchemaTool.getNucleusContextForMode(SchemaTool.java:693)
    at org.datanucleus.store.schema.SchemaTool.main(SchemaTool.java:286)
An error was encountered creating a PersistenceManagerFactory : There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType" - please consult the log for more information.
```

**UPD** If i remove the `<scope>runtime</scope>` restriction from `datanucleus-rdbms`, I get the following error:

```
~>2015-02-23 12:07:34 DEBUG MetaData:58 - Class "hello.Counter" field "count" : Adding Meta-Data for field since it didnt appear in the Meta-Data definition.
~>2015-02-23 12:07:34 DEBUG MetaData:58 - Initialising all MetaData ...
~>2015-02-23 12:07:34 DEBUG MetaData:58 - Class "hello.Counter" : Initialising Meta-Data
~>2015-02-23 12:07:34 DEBUG MetaData:58 - MetaData Management : Load of Metadata complete
~>2015-02-23 12:07:34 DEBUG Datastore:58 - Creating StoreManager for datastore
~>2015-02-23 12:07:34 ERROR Datastore:125 - Exception thrown creating StoreManager. See the nested exception
Error creating transactional connection factory
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Error creating transactional connection factory
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:219)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:163)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:193)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.datanucleus.store.schema.SchemaTool.getNucleusContextForMode(SchemaTool.java:693)
    at org.datanucleus.store.schema.SchemaTool.main(SchemaTool.java:286)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:330)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:205)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
    ... 19 more
Nested Throwables StackTrace:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:330)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:205)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:163)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:193)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.datanucleus.store.schema.SchemaTool.getNucleusContextForMode(SchemaTool.java:693)
    at org.datanucleus.store.schema.SchemaTool.main(SchemaTool.java:286)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Why not run the tutorial at the DataNucleus site because that works for me, and only you know what you changed from it. Clearly the persistence.xml has to be in META-INF from the root of the CLASSPATH, and if it isn't then you give it no chance to know where your database is

Comment: The folder _was_ META-INF, I called it wrong here in the text. Also, I added some fields to the pom, and now it is obvious that persistence.xml is read and parsed, however the schema creation step fails. I suspect it might be to do with the fact that i try to inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent.

Comment: @NeilStockton With your help, I now seem a few steps from the goal. I now get the «There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc".» error. I updated my post accordingly. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH` says all you really need to know. The datanucleus-rdbms plugin is NOT in the CLASSPATH ... your scope restriction on `runtime`

Comment: Without the runtime restriction, i get another error. I updated the question with it.

Comment: You can't run SchemaTool without the plugin that controls the datastore. Why you get that other error I can't answer and suggested that you run the official DataNucleus tutorial which works just fine ... so obviously you have changed something relative to it